# Creating an iframe from JQuery - properties are not working, why not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello im creating an iframe in my javascript. However the style and the loaded event doesnt seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
var iframe = $("<iframe src='/Player/ShowPage/"+data.PageId+"'/>", {
                            style: "position:absolute; left:-100%",
                            load: function () {
                                var that = this;
                                $(this).animate({
                                    left: 0
                                }, 500);
                                $('iframe').not(this).animate({
                                    left: '-100%'
                                }, 500, function () {
                                    $('iframe').not(that).remove();
                                });
                            }
                        });
                        $('body').append(iframe);
```

I must be missing something, I just cant figure out what it is. The iframe is just sitting there - mocking me - on the screen...

Comment: The attribute is named `onload`, not `load`.

Comment: or use `iframe.on('load',func....`

Comment: whats buggin me, is that the "style" isnt working either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the 'src' into the object literal and everything works fine.

```
var iframe = $("<iframe>", {
    src: '/Player/ShowPage/' + data.PageId,
    style: "position:absolute; left:-100%",
    load: function () {
        var that = this;
        $(this).animate({
            left: 0
        }, 500);
        $('iframe').not(this).animate({
            left: '-100%'
        }, 500, function () {
            $('iframe').not(that).remove();
        });
    }
});
$('body').append(iframe);
```

Please check this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/marianc/drm2f4d2/) for a working demo.

Comment: Yesss....seems odd to me, but its just one of those things you try not to think too much about. Thanks.